# Warnings in GGTS using grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I'm starting a project using grails and have installed several versions: 2.3.8, 2.4.1. But when I create a new project in GGTS version 3.5.1 with the platform Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 using grails 2.3.8 a yellow warning sign next to the project name appears in the project explorer; and the Markers window I get the following description `The resource is a duplicate of .link_to_grails_plugins/hibernate-3.6.10.13/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties and was not copied to the output folder` Resource `messages.properties` and Type `Java Problem`

If I create a project using  grails 2.4.1 a big red mark "!" appears next to the project name and a popup windows stating that "Building Workspace" has encountered a problem. The specific deatils are the following:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'Indicat2'.
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.count(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lgroovy>/lang/Closure;)Ljava/lang/Number;

Im using Fedora 19 with latest updates, jdk 1.7.0_55

I've searched the web but nothing useful has come up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that particular error and in those cases it was because the wrong Groovy compiler level was being used. Grails 2.4 requires the Groovy 2.3 compiler.

Double check that your workspace is configured to use the correct Groovy compiler. Go to 'Window >> Preferences >> Groovy >> Compiler'.

It should tell you there what version of Groovy is being used by the Greclipse compiler. It also lets you switch to a different one. If you don't have a 2.3 compiler as an option there you probably need to install it. I don't beleave it was installed by default with GGTS 3.5.1.

Rather than trying to install a newer version of Groovy Eclipse with 2.3 support, it may be better to install GGTS 3.6.0.M1 (or newer) instead. This should come with the Groovy 2.3 compiler pre-installed.